# Having difficultly getting the frequency back from a Cypher query

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm working on university course recommender system using Neo4j and have hit a brick wall with this problem.

What I want to do is give the system an interest, this interest will then be checked against students in the system who have a relationship with that interest (:HAS_INTEREST) and then return all the courses the students are enrolled in, with the frequency they appear in the search (the course(s) with the most students will be recommended). For that I use this query:

```
MATCH (interest:Interest {description:"Computing"})<-[:HAS_INTEREST]-(student:Student),
(student)-[:ENROLLED_IN]->(course:Course)
RETURN course.title, count(course) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 25
```

The query returns the data I want (course name and frequency of occurrence) when I type the query in using the Neo4j browser but my problem occurs when I try to make the cypher query in c#; I can't get the frequency for each course. I can return all the courses and even have then ordered but I need the frequency that they appeared to give a proper recommendation. I'll lay out my code below

**Course Class**

```
    public class Course
    {
        public string title { get; set; }

        public long fequency { get; set; }
    }
```

**Cypher Query**

```
        public static IEnumerable<Course> GetCourseRecommendation(string interest)
        {
        var data = GraphClient.Cypher
           .Match("(i:Interest {description : {interestDesc} })<-[:HAS_INTEREST]-(student:Student)", "(student)-[:ENROLLED_IN]->(course: Course)")
           .WithParam("interestDesc", interest)
           .With((course, c) => new
           {
               course = course.As<Course>(),
               c = course.Count()
           })
           .Return(course => course.As<Course>())
           .OrderByDescending("c")
           .Limit(25)
           .Results;

        return data;
        }
```

I added the frequency attribute to the Course class to see if I could store it there but no luck, I've tried alot of different varations of the .net query to see if I can get the frequency out of it but nothing seems to work, it just returns the courses.

tl;dr I need to get the frequency of how many times a course appears in a query result and do not know how to get this information using the .Net library.

**Edit : Answer**

Thanks to *Supamiu* and *Chris Skardon* for giving an answer and an explanation to the issue. Final working query is listed below, this returns both the courses and the frequency that they appear in the query.

```
            var data = GraphClient.Cypher
               .Match("(i:Interest {description : {interestDesc} })<-[:HAS_INTEREST]-(student:Student)", "(student)-[:ENROLLED_IN]->(course: Course)")
               .WithParam("interestDesc", interest)
               .Return((course, c) => new
               {
                   course = course.As<Course>(),
                   c = course.Count()
               })
               .OrderByDescending("c")
               .Limit(25)
               .Results;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you store `course` and `frequency` in two different variables within your query, if you want to add frequency to your course, you'l have to set it later on like `course.setFrequency(c)`.

Actually you are doing `Return(course => course.As<Course>())` but `course` only contains title, since frequency is stored in `c`. So you have to get `c` too and set it in `course` later on.

Comment: This is the right answer - code wise - you probably want to replace the `.With` with a `.Return` and delete the other `Return` call, that would get you what you're after

Comment: Thanks for help, that has done it. I understand what Supamiu was saying and tried Chris's suggestion and got them both back, seems so obvious to me now.